# Copy values to a sheet containing formulas without formulas being removed

Tags: vba, excel

I have two Worksheets: Sheet1 and Sheet2. Sheet1 has raw data (without any formulas), Sheet2 has formulas in some cells. Is it possible to copy values from Sheet1 to Sheet2 without formulas being removed from Sheet2?

I am using the following code to copy values from sheet1 to sheet2. After values are copied, formulas in Sheet2 get removed.

```
i = 2

With Sheets(1)
   'loop column A 
   For Each Cell In .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
      .Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Range("A" & i)
      i = i + 1
   Next Cell
End With
```

Comment: Formulas shouldn't be the problem. Overwriting seems like being the problem. If you don't want to overwrite cells with formulas add a test that the cell being written to doesn't have a formula with HasFormula or Left(cell.value,1) = "="

Comment: You are also copying an entire row so are you expecting to test whether any cell within the destination row has a formula?

Comment: Sheet2 is always empty, only contains a bunch of formulas. It is supposed to act like a calculator. It gets input and produces output, and then get cleaned for the new set of values. I want the formulas to stay there. But the code removes formulas.

Comment: 1) Sheet 2 is therefore not empty (sorry to be pedantic) 2) Why not simply choose to output to a different range where there are no formulas?

Comment: 1) Sorry I meant there are no values in it, only formulas. 2) It just doesn't look very professional if it jumps to some random place. ;-) I want everything to be in-place. But if there is no way to do it... I should go with your suggestion.

Comment: I guess I am finding it hard to visualise your data and desired outcome. That is where providing examples pays dividends. You have formulas - where do those formula point to, to perform their calculations? It shouldn't be that difficult to work with only used ranges (not entire rows) and output to the side of the formulas (left or right - which ever suits). Just make sure formulas reference new position. And thinking about it....if doing this, why don't the formulas simply point at the other sheet and avoid copying altogether? It feels like, I don't know, this could be  a design question.

Comment: You are right! I will provide some examples to make the problem more clear. But it's too late here... will do it tomorrow! :-)

Comment: You are copy pasting raw values into cells which contain a formula and expect the formula to still be there after doing so? Not possible and sounds strange, unless you want to loop through each cell in a row and paste cells individually and check for the existence of a formula beforehand. I'll add an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This code will not copypaste the whole row but will loop through each cell in your row on the raw data and only copypaste the value when in the same cell on your other sheet no formula excists:

```
Sub TestForFormula()

Dim X As Long
Dim CL As Range, RNG As Range

For X = 2 To Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set RNG = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(X, 1), Cells(X, ActiveSheet.Cells(X, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
    For Each CL In RNG
        If Sheets(2).Cells(X, CL.Column).HasFormula = False Then
            Sheets(2).Cells(X, CL.Column).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(X, CL.Column).Value
        End If
    Next CL
Next X

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I might go with a combination of your code and @QHarr suggestion. That should put me on the right direction to find the solution.